# Timeout while creating applications from Central Admin

Tags: central-administration, web-application

For the last few days I have been unable to create a new application through central administration. The creation times out.

I have searched high and low through the internet. **Every other site says that you should change the timeout thresholds in IIS but in my case it doesn't work.** I have changed start, shutdown and ping timeouts for all application pools to 600 seconds. Application creation is still timing out at about 2-3 minutes.

The applicatin does get created, along with its database, but there are no files in its virtual folder. It stays completely unusable.

Help? How do I solve this?

By the way... I'm trying to create the application with a service account which was configured through the wizard, belongs to all the necessary groups and is dbowner in all the databases in the SQL Server. So if it is a permission issue, it is a pretty hairy one.

Comment: 1. look at the SharePoint log. You may have to bump up the logging to verbose 2. Have you try creating application using PowerShell?

Comment: Which part takes a long time - creating the web application or creating the default site collection?

Comment: @MariaBurton Thanks for the tip, I will look into that.

Comment: @DaveWise creating the application. I can't even create a site collection.

Comment: @MariaBurton I just want to thank you very much. I still can't create applications through CA, and I can't figure out why, but I tried to create them via Powershell and it worked like a charm. I'm going to go through that route for the while being.

Comment: Is the SharePoint Administration service running on all servers in the farm?

Comment: @DaveWise It's just one machine, standalone.